construct a androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Outline from a Drawable
I have the following problem to solve, namely that given an xml file, I am required to use this to clip an image (and I am using Jetpack compose). It's not a simple corner, or rounded rectangle, etc...
If the fate of the world depended on me solving this problem without third-party libraries (unless well known and well supported) I would probably inspect the pathData in the raw xml file, then from this create an androidx.compose.graphics.ui.Outline (creating the path using lineTo, cubicTo, etc...), then subclassing androidx.compose.graphics.ui.Shape use this custom shape in Modifier.clip() (I have indeed tried this and the result looks reasonable).
However it is not the end of the world so this probably isn't going to get past the PR process (because it's not easy to follow, it's a brittle solution if the path needs to change, and it feels like I'm reinventing a wheel). Is there any well supported way, starting from a drawable resource file of getting to a compose Outline? I know that from a VectorDrawable, I can construct an android.graphics.Outline via Drawable::getOutline(Outline) but though this Outline class defines setPath it does not define getPath (which I was hoping to then, somehow, transform into a compose Path and then finally construct a compose Outline)
I've been googling around and coming up short, does anybody have any ideas?
Alternatively using XML views, can the effect of clipping an image from a non trivial drawable be done using standard android APIs (for android versions going back as far as android 9)?
